# PGFPlot not plotting 1/x^2

Tags: tikz-pgf

i have always use PGFPlot for basic 2D function graphique. However, I'm unable to plot 1/x^2 with the following code (i included all my documents packages even if only tikz and pgfplot are used here).

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nameref} % For reference
\usepackage{hyperref} % url reference
\usepackage{tikz} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{automata} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % state diagram x and y 
\usepackage{amsmath} % For matrix in state machine
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{beramono} % monospaced font with bold variant
\usepackage{lastpage} % To add lastpage référence.
\usepackage{siunitx} % For microsecond
\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code
\usepackage{eso-pic} % Title background

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.6, every node/.style={transform shape}]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $d$, ylabel=$P$
        %ymin=-1, xmin=0
        %ymax=0, xmax=0
        ]
        \addplot[samples=200, color=blue, domain=0:1]{1/(x*x)};
        \legend{$\frac{1}{x^2}$}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

  \end{document}
```

This produces the following output:[image: Output]

How to get a proper graph between 0 and 2-3, without a high value in y axis ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thats right for x=0...1. If you want also 0...-1. Add `domain=-1:1`.

Comment: This plot is correct. Did you not notice that the `y axis` is labeled in multiples of `10^4` ? Maybe you should stay away from 0 in your `domain=` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following function *is* technically plotted correctly, however your sketchy way of setting `domain` causes a pile of problems. I used `\pgfplotsset` to set the `xmin`, `xmax` and `ymin`, `ymax` that couldn't be included in `\axis` square brackets (the reason is unknown).

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nameref} % For reference
\usepackage{hyperref} % url reference
\usepackage{tikz} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{automata} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % state diagram x and y 
\usepackage{amsmath} % For matrix in state machine
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{beramono} % monospaced font with bold variant
\usepackage{lastpage} % To add lastpage référence.
\usepackage{siunitx} % For microsecond
\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code
\usepackage{eso-pic} % Title background

\pgfplotsset{xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=0, ymax=3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %[scale=0.6, every node/.style={transform shape}]
        \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $d$, ylabel=$P$, restrict y to domain=0:5]
        \addplot[samples=200, color=blue]{1/(x*x)};
        \legend{$\frac{1}{x^2}$}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output: `x=2, y=3` result you desire.

[image]

However, the aspect ratio in this plot *isn't* `1:1` but rather `2:1`. If you want to have a `1:1` aspect ratio plot, you have to include `axis equal` in `axis` square brackets. However, this produces a strange result I haven't been able to fix myself. I'll post it anyway as you might know how a workaround. Again, the code + `axis equal`:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nameref} % For reference
\usepackage{hyperref} % url reference
\usepackage{tikz} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % State diagram
\usetikzlibrary{automata} 
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % state diagram x and y 
\usepackage{amsmath} % For matrix in state machine
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{beramono} % monospaced font with bold variant
\usepackage{lastpage} % To add lastpage référence.
\usepackage{siunitx} % For microsecond
\usepackage{listings} % Required for insertion of code
\usepackage{eso-pic} % Title background

\pgfplotsset{xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=0, ymax=3}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %[scale=0.6, every node/.style={transform shape}]
        \begin{axis}[axis equal,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $d$, ylabel=$P$, restrict y to domain=0:5]
        \addplot[samples=200, color=blue]{1/(x*x)};
        \legend{$\frac{1}{x^2}$}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

And the result.

[image]